# pyspark dataframe column creation

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm beginner in pyspark. I have this problem where I have a vector column / list of values.

```
col = ["True", "False", "True"]
```

I want to create a column in dataframe (with 3 rows) with this vector / list of values. E.g., in pandas we can do `df['col_name'] = col`.

Comment: do you want to create a new dataframe or add a new column in an existing dataframe?

Comment: I think the thing to keep in mind here is that PySpark has no concept of order whereas this syntax assumes so. I think this thinking is not compatible with PySpark, which is why it doesn't have such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Spark don't have such function that work well in Pandas, you can can still achieve it by using joining. Assuming you have a sorted dataframe and a list of new value that want to be the new column:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([('a', ), ('b', ), ('c', )], ['column'])
df.show(3, False)
+------+----------+
|column|row_number|
+------+----------+
|a     |1         |
|b     |2         |
|c     |3         |
+------+----------+
```

You can add a row number and do the joining:

```
new_add_column = spark.createDataFrame([(True, ), (False, ), (True, )], ['new_create_column'])\
    .withColumn('row_number', func.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(func.lit(''))))
new_add_column.show(3, False)
+------+----------+
|column|row_number|
+------+----------+
|a     |1         |
|b     |2         |
|c     |3         |
+------+----------+

new_add_column = spark.createDataFrame([(True, ), (False, ), (True, )], ['new_create_column'])\
    .withColumn('row_number', func.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(func.lit(''))))
new_add_column.show(3, False)
+-----------------+----------+
|new_create_column|row_number|
+-----------------+----------+
|true             |1         |
|false            |2         |
|true             |3         |
+-----------------+----------+

output = df.join(new_add_column, on='row_number', how='inner')
output.show(3, False)
+----------+------+-----------------+
|row_number|column|new_create_column|
+----------+------+-----------------+
|1         |a     |true             |
|2         |b     |false            |
|3         |c     |true             |
+----------+------+-----------------+
```